# How do I cache control?

Tags: cache-control, browser-cache

How do I get my website to save images to clients computer and use them, not redownload them every page reload?

I tried to send header("Cache-Control: max-age=3600"); but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to sand caching headers *for the image files*, not for your HTML document. You can use the `header` function only if the files are actually served by a PHP script - not if they are static files handled by the web server. If they are static files, check the documentation for your web server of choice.

Also consider sending en [Expires](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires) header, and [disable ETags](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags).

Comment: I checked the documentation, nothing happened o_O